# Find word in a string where word is not present as a whole instead it's scattered

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to find a word "`little`" in a string but word in the string is not present as a whole.

For eg. `input string="aalbeiedteetoolpue"` or `"lliittttllleee"`

Comment: Is this just for a couple of words/ one time script OR does this code need to run on thousands of words/ in production code?

Comment: In the latter case (if you have tested/ know that regex will take too long for your case), you might want to have a look at [Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) and its [Dynamic Programming solutions](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-4-longest-common-subsequence/)

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try this:

```
\b\w*l\w*i\w*t\w*t\w*l\w*e\w*\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YgNUGK/1)

Comment: I like to know is there any way to do this!